# Is there a way to permutate list of lists while keeping the lists together?

Tags: list, math, nested, combinations, permutation

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Is there anyway possible in the realm of coding that I can permutate this list of lists while keeping the "groups" together?
I really need this solved, been working on a code all week and this is like the last step.

Result should look something like this or close:

```
permuations_list1 = [[2,3,1],[6,5,4],[8,9,7]], [[3,2,1],[4,5,6],[8,7,9]], .......
```

I have searched over alot of sites for a solution, but none of them keep the original lists grouped together. Anything helps.

Comment: For which programming language? What you have looks like Python, but doesn't have that tag.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be split into two steps:

1. Generate all permutations for each sublist
2. Generate all unique combinations of `(perm_X_of_sublist_1, perm_Y_of_sublist_2, perm_Z_of_sublist_3)`

In python, a working solution would look like this:

```py
import itertools
# step 1 - generate all permutations for each sublist
permutated_sublists = (itertools.permutations(sublist) for sublist in list1)
# step 2 - generate a cartesian product of permutated sublists and gather results
permutations_list = list(itertools.product(*permutated_sublists))
```

The result will look like this

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
 [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 9, 8]],
 [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [8, 7, 9]],
 ... (212 more combinations) 
 [[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7]]]
```